# asp.net MVC bundling with babel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, babeljs

Is it possible to use babel in asp.net mvc without webpack?
With the use of standard bundling available in the starter project?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible of course - msbuild is powerfull build system. In cases what I know it was done through gulp (call gulp tasks on compile).

But this is wrong way because you will need to spend your time on tooling when what you need is start developing as soon as possible. So stay with open terminal window, and run `npm run my-compile` manually.